# Get author usernames from YouTube Data API videos feeds

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

Surprisingly, YouTube's Data API only gives the display name of the author with each video in a video feed. The display name is not unique. This is very annoying. I need the unique username for various reasons. One of which, is to construct the URL for that user's profile/channel.

How might I get the username of the author (as opposed to the non-unique display name) of a YouTube video?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: it's not a duplicate. I acknowledged that it "only gives the display name of the author". I need the username. The display name is not unique.

Comment: @MikeBrant "How might I get the username of the author (as opposed to the non-unique display name) of a youtube video?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[snippet.channelId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#snippet.channelId) is the unique channel which the video is uploaded into. That's what you are looking for.
More information on [channelId vs username](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/working_with_channel_ids).

Comment: thanks. i was using v2 of the API, didn't see this in v3.